# Wrong diacritic letters in Integrated Terminal of Visual Studio Code with PowerShell between Run and Run Selection

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code

I have the Windows 10 with Windows-1250 encoding but in Visual Studio Code with integrated terminal I have problems with diacritic signs:

[image]

As you see encoding is different between Run and Run Selection of same command: `write-host "Wspólny"`
My JSON user configuration is empty, I've been trying for several hours but no solution helps. I want UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: If you want UTF-8 everywhere, why do you have code page 1250 configured?

Comment: I didn't precisely define myself - I want UTF8 within Visual Studio Code and PowerShell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation:

- You're running *Windows PowerShell*, which reads its source code based on the system's active ANSI code page (`1250` in your example).
- By contrast, Visual Studio Code creates *BOM-less UTF-8*-encoded files by default.
- In the absence of a BOM in a source code file (or any text file that Windows PowerShell reads, such as with `Get-Content`), *ANSI* encoding is assumed, so the UTF-8 file is *misinterpreted*.

  - Specifically, *each individual byte* of any non-ASCII character - which in UTF-8 is always encoded as a *multi-byte* sequence - is then interpreted as an ANSI character.
  - Note: This is no longer a problem in PowerShell (Core) 7+, which consistently defaults to UTF-8, both on reading BOM-less files and when writing files (BOM-less UTF-8).

Therefore, the solution is to **save your source code** - or any UTF-8 files you want Windows PowerShell to read correctly - **as UTF-8 *with BOM***.

You also need to do this for source code you want to run properly in *both* editions of PowerShell.

Comment: While some Windows documentation still calls the legacy code pages "ANSI", it's really a misnomer, and even Microsoft is trying to deprecate this terminology (just with their usual levels of competence and commitment).

Comment: @tripleee, yes, these code pages never became ANSI standards (though that was seemingly the intent), but the misnomer will (unfortunately) probably not go away, given that there is a need to distinguish the _two_ active code pages implied by the chosen system locale ("language for non-Unicode programs"): The "ANSI" code page vs. the _OEM_ code page. The `A` for "ANSI" is part of many system function names, registry entries, ... Certainly, the documentation could at least mention the misnomer somewhere, but that appears not to be the case.

Comment: @tripleee: To put it differently: the primary purpose of "ANSI" in the context of Windows code pages is to refer to the code pages used by (legacy) _GUI_ applications, as opposed to the _OEM_ code pages used by (legacy) _console_ applications - which in itself is a very unfortunate historical bifurcation.