# Why won't PowerShell script find character?

Tags: powershell, replace, control-characters

I have a PowerShell script that runs daily and is used to filter through all the files in a folder as there are 2000+ and do a find and replace of a character and replace with a linebreak. Character shows as, up arrow character in notepad, an FF character in notepad++

I have images below as well

```
$filename = Get-ChildItem "C:\Scripts\*filename*.*"
$filename | % {
    (gc $_) -replace "","`n`f" | Set-Content $_.fullname
}
```

As seen, in the code block it doesn't show the arrow, but as text it does. I can do a manual find and replace but when it runs the PowerShell script from the task schedule it doesn't pick anything up to replace it seems. Is there a different way of going about this?

Any help is appreciated!

[image: Code Snippet Screenshot]

Comment: ```-replace "`f", "`n`f"```

Comment: Please clarify what specific character you're trying to replace. If it is indeed the FF (Form Feed) character, then Mathias' suggestion should work for you. As a general tip: if you want Windows PowerShell to interpret your source-code files correctly, save them as UTF-8 _with a BOM_ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67140903/45375).

Comment: Brad, looking at the image, we can't figure out the exact character that is.  Probably Unicode, I know the characters with a value less than 32 show odd symbols too.  If you use a tool like HxD, you can load a file into memory as hex bytes.  Can take a little bit to understand, but you can figure out what exact sequence of bytes are at a spot in the file. From there, we can figure out the Unicode character that needs to be replaced.

Comment: Brad, I've edited my answer below with new information and a possible answer.

Comment: Another thing to take into account is to use `gc -raw` to load the whole file as 1 string instead of a lines array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my guess as to what's going on.  Replacing formfeed 0C "`f" with carriage return, linefeed 0D 0A "`r`n" (windows text).

```
"hi`fhow are you`f" | set-content file.txt -NoNewline
format-hex file.txt


           Path: C:\users\admin\foo\file.txt

           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   68 69 0C 68 6F 77 20 61 72 65 20 79 6F 75 0C     hi.how are you.


(get-content file.txt) -replace "`f","`r`n" | set-content file2.txt -NoNewline
format-hex file2.txt


           Path: C:\users\admin\foo\file2.txt

           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   68 69 0D 0A 68 6F 77 20 61 72 65 20 79 6F 75 0D  hi..how are you.
00000010   0A                                               .
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in tests, by default Get-Content doesn't default to getting content in Unicode format, so I'd guess it's defaulting to ASCII (but don't know for sure).

So in your script you'll want to specify the encoding to force it to use that. I'd also suggest referencing the specific character via it's UNICODE number rather than the symbol, that way you don't need to worry about the format of the script file, or the editor you're using. The following should do what you need (or at least does on my machine).

```
$filename = Get-ChildItem "C:\Scripts\unicode.txt"
$filename | % {
    (gc -Encoding utf8 $_) -replace "\u2191","`n`r" | Set-Content $_.fullname
}
```

Comment: Powershell 5 doesn't recognize utf8 no bom encoded scripts.

Comment: On my Windows 10 box with PS5 that code with utf8 works fine.

Comment: Without a bom, special characters will mess it up.  I mean without the -encoding parameter.

Comment: Keith, I have Win10 and PS5, doing Write-Host "[\u2191]" results in "[\u2191]". Also, the character Brad is showing isn't an up arrow but 0x2660, a Spade from a deck of cards - Write-Host "[$([char]0x2660)]".

Comment: @Darin, leaving aside that the code point may be the wrong one, note that `\u2191` is a _regex_ escape sequence, interpreted by the _.NET regex engine_, not by PowerShell; try `"\`f" -match '\u000c'`, for instance.

Comment: Darin - Yeah, using Write-Host to output the character like that doesn't work... but the -replace statement does (I created a test file and confirmed it works). Ahh, thought it looked like an up arrow on my screen, but obviously the same code works with the relevant code for the required character.

Comment: As for `Get-Content`: Both PowerShell editions recognize Unicode encodings _if the file has a BOM_. In the absence of a BOM, _Windows PowerShell_ defaults to the system's active legacy _ANSI_ code page, whereas _PowerShell (Core)_ (v6+) now consistently defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8.

Comment: Darin - Actually, zooming in on the image (since the character doesn't show in the question text) it doesn't look like a spade to me at all, it doesn't have rounded edges like a spade, they're angular... like an arrow.

Comment: Keith, sorry, didn't realize RegEx did unicode and that was the syntax.  As for the arrow/spade, I do not know what that is.  I'm looking through Character Map and Lucida Console's spade is a close match, but as you pointed out, it does not have sharp edges.  But what font has a fat arrow with a shaft?  All the arrows I'm finding are either thin or don't have the shaft.  I've looked all common fonts, may look a second time, I don't know.

Comment: In powershell 7, you can do something like `"\`u{2191}"` to make a `↑`.  The question is probably about a formfeed `"\`f"`.

Comment: Odd a formfeed prints as a unicode female sign `♀` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I figured out what character you are having problems with.  It appears to be 0x0C.  I used HxD to edit a text file and placed all the characters from 0x00 to 0x1F in there and found 0x0C was the fat up arrow.

I've rewrote this code to what should work.  But if it doesn't then try Keith's answer and replace the "\u2191" with "\u000C", or if that doesn't work, maybe try "\u0C" in his code.  Not sure how RegEx works with unicode, but it should be something like this.

```
(gc $_) -replace "$([char]0x0C)","`n" | Set-Content $_.fullname
```

**EDIT:**

In the comments below mklement0 pointed out that this should be the Form Feed character.  That being the case, then this version should work.

```
(gc $_) -replace "`f","`n" | Set-Content $_.fullname
```

But if none these work, then don't forget to try Keith's version - and try both the "`f" and the Unicode "\u000C" variations with his code.

Comment: Re-reading the question, it does say "replace with a linebreak", so your replacement string makes sense (although there's still ambiguity around whether it should be a LF or CRLF line break, unfortunately). Tip: you can use a `[char]` cast as-is with `-replace` - no need to explicitly convert it to a string; e.g. `"\`f" -replace [char] 0xc, 'FF'`

Comment: Sorry if It got a bit confusing, trying to manage the question while also not using the data I had to edit some so I may of messed up a part. BUT I think I got it to run finally using the $([char]0x0C). So I will put this to test as it may work now. So I appreciate everyone's help with this!